# How to query specific field in django JSON field

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a model, which has JSON field called `data`. I need to query all models, which have `type` in this `data` field, which starts with string `gpa.`

Corresponding query is:

```
select data ->> 'type' from model where data ->> 'type' like 'gpa.%'
```

How can I do this using querysets? All I could find is an exact match, not startswith. I am using django 1.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have data jsonfield, and you are searching value of key named type starts with 'gpa.'.You can try this:

```
Model.objects.filter(data__type__startswith='gpa.')
```